# Adding additional cell to top of UITableView Issues

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uitableview, nsarray

I've read a few SO posts regarding this issue, but seem to be having issues (hair pulling included of course) adding an additional cell to the top of a UITableView.  Here is my code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // self.StringArray has 5 string objects inside
    return ([self.stringArray count] + 1);
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // create hardcoded first row in table
    if([indexPath row] == 0)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Select me";
    }
    else
    {
        // decrement the row to get the correct object from the self.stringArray
        int arrayIndex = [indexPath row] - 1;
        cell.textLabel.text = [self.stringArray objectAtIndex:arrayIndex];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Everything looks good (obviously something is wrong though if I'm getting exception error), but I can't seem to eyeball it.

Exception: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 5 beyond bounds [0 .. 4]'

Comment: are you returning the cell at the end of your '- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
' method?

Comment: @KrishnaK - It looks like a bad copy/paste, so I added it into the code sample.  It is present in my original code though.

Comment: I tried it out in xcode and your code executes without any exceptions. As far as I can tell, from this code, stringArray contents are being modified in between the two calls above. Try checking the count value when you return in numberOfRowsInSection.

Comment: @KrishnaK - See my Answer below =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.  I overlooked the fact that I didn't account for the other UITableView delegate methods, and I didn't account for this extra row in the UITableView when setting up the logic for the tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath method.  Here is the code that fixed the problem:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // I added code here to intercept the added row (row 0) and make it non-editable
    if([indexPath row] == 0)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    else
    {
        // decrement the row to get the correct object from the self.stringArray    
        int arrayIndex = [indexPath row] - 1;
        if([[self.stringArray objectAtIndex:arrayIndex] length] > 10)
        {
            return YES;
        }
        else
        {
            return NO;
        }
    }
}
```